# How to add $scope.$on to view without controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-listener

I use a plugin in Angular app that fires a `$rootScope.$broadcast('signinBegin')`. I want to show a `preloader` with `ng-if` but I don't have access to this controller for adding `$scope.$on('signinBegin',function(){...})`. How to show preloader without controller when event start in HTML view?

```
<div ng-if="preloader">
    <img src="../assets/img/preloader/material.gif" alt="preloader">
</div>
<div id="sign-form" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">         
                <!--  ng-submit should be signin() -->
                <form ng-submit="signin()" role="form" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>                                      
                        <div  class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            <input ng-model="user.email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacing"></div>
                        <div  class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                            <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacing"></div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm  pull-right">Sign In</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <a ui-sref="forget-password" class="grey">Forget Password?</a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this app.config

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,$authProvider) {
    $authProvider.signinState = 'login';
    $authProvider.signinRoute = '/login';
```

I use [ng-AA](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA) plugin.

Thanks

Comment: How is this view being added in the first place?

Comment: can you add your code here? or can you post code here?

Comment: I added code. I don't have controller for this page

Comment: can you create plunker with your requirement? or can you explain clearly?

Comment: I can't  create plunker because this code related to my back-end and it complex. I have problem like [this](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA/issues/19). I use this library to login. the author of this plugin write [event](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA/commit/c892bd5b0fab07415477749fa7e7e5b7702f07d8) as `signinBegin`. by the documentation I don't need to define controller. Now I want to use this  event to show preloader. I think it's clear.

Comment: thanks for your reply i'll check and tell you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make use of directives. For example:

```
myApp.directive('signinBeginFoo', function() {
   return {
       scope: true,
       link: function($scope) {
           $scope.$on('signinBegin', function() {
               $scope.preloader = true;
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Now, modify your DOM:

```
<signin-begin-foo>
    <div ng-if="preloader">
        <img src="../assets/img/preloader/material.gif" alt="preloader">
    </div>
</signin-begin-foo>
```